# MYSQL pivot table with join

Tags: mysql, join, pivot-table

I have the following two tables and want to have pivot table as result:

**table 1 (name: search_keywords):**
id | product_id | keyword | active

**table 2 (name: keyword_ranking):**
id | search_keyword_id | eval_date | rank

search_keywords.id is foreign key in table 2: keyword_ranking.search_keyword_id

as result I need the following table:

***eval_date   | keyword1 | keyword 2 | keyword 3 ...***

01.01.2015 | 2 | 4 | 12 ... ---> rank (for each keyword)

02.01.2015 | 1 | 6 | 10 ... ---> rank (for each keyword)

03.01.2015 | 3 | 5 | 9 ... ---> rank (for each keyword)

It is important to note, that I do not know how many keywords are in table 1, so the columns need to be dynamic.

Only data with product_id = ? and active = 'Y' should be displayed

Here my table as image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a solution with prepared statements as follows:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT  
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
    'MAX(IF(sk.keywords = ''', sk.keywords,''', kr.rank, NULL)) AS ',  CONCAT('`',sk.keywords, '`')
    )
) INTO @sql
 FROM 
     search_keywords sk;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT eval_date, ', @sql, '  
                   FROM keyword_ranking AS kr 
                   LEFT JOIN  search_keywords AS sk 
                    ON kr.search_keywords_id = sk.id 
                   GROUP BY eval_date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```